# How to create an instance with part of the methods of a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have class A with methods X and Y. Now I want to create an instance but only want it to have method X from class A.

How should I do it? Should it be by deleting method Y for the instance when creating it? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: That is a strange thing to do. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: As @RenatoZannon is saying, this is strange. I suspect you should refactor and use a module in stead. `module ModuleWithX` and `module ModuleWithY` and then in your new class do `include ModuleWithX`

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this. You should instead share the problem you're solving and find a better pattern for solving it.

---

An example for solving this problem a little differently:

```
class A
  def x; end
end

module Foo
  def y; end
end

instance_with_y = A.new
instance_with_y.send :include, Foo
instance_with_y.respond_to? :y #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do what you want with ruby, as ruby can be very malleable like that, but there are much better ways. What you want to achieve seems like a really bad idea.

The problem you just described a problem inheritance is designed to solve.  So really, you have two classes. Class `A` and also class `B` which inherits from class `A`.

```
class A
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

# B inherits all functionality from A, plus adds it's own
class B < A
  def bar
    'bar'
  end
end

# an instance of A only has the method "foo"
a = A.new
a.foo #=> 'foo'
a.bar #=> NoMethodError undefined method `bar' for #<A:0x007fdf549dee88>

# an instance of B has the methods "foo" and "bar"
b = B.new
b.foo #=> 'foo'
b.bar #=> 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve the problem :

```
class X
  def a 
    11
  end
  def b
    12
  end
end

ob1 = X.new
ob1.b # => 12
ob1.singleton_class.class_eval { undef b }
ob1.b
# undefined method `b' for #<X:0x9966e60> (NoMethodError)
```

or, you could write as ( above and below both are same ) :

```
class << ob1
  undef b
end

ob1.b
# undefined method `b' for #<X:0x93a3b54> (NoMethodError)
```